# How to push wiki to github

Tags: git, github, wiki

I cloned wiki of my repository and edited locally, it failed when I push the changes to Github. [The help of wiki operation](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-and-editing-wiki-pages-locally/) is very short, I cannot figure it out. Please help if you know how to fix this. Thanks.

[image: problem picture]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the same operation in command line:

Once you have cloned your wiki locally, and modified/added files, do:

```
cd /path/to/local/cloned/wiki
git add .
git commit -m "new files"
git push
```

Comment: only I get this error now: _“ERROR: Authentication error: Authentication required: You must have push access to verify locks”_

Comment: @Martin What URL are you using? What does `git remote -v` return in your local wiki clone? What does `git version` return? And what is your OS?

Comment: `https://github.com/krischik/SteemRubyTutorial.wiki.git` and **git version 2.23.0**

Comment: @Martin Is krischik your GitHub login: meaning, do you own the repository (and its wiki) to which you want to push?

Comment: Yes it is. I do own the Repository. The strange thing is: It did work 9 month “Wed Jul 31” ago. The real question is: What changed?

Comment: @Martin Interesting. Can you ask a separate question, with more details on your current setup, for others to chime in.

Comment: Finally figured it out: lfs sneaked itself into the wiki clone and wiki repositories don't support lfs.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @VonC answer: Make sure not to use lfs (Large File Storage) for the wiki. Remove lfs support from your global setting and activate lfs separately for each repository.

To uninstall lfs:

```
cd /path/to/local/cloned/wiki
git lfs uninstall
```

To reinstall lf in repositories supporting lfs:

```
cd /path/to/local/cloned/repository
git lfs install --local
```

Comment: Can you explain why this should be done? This is the first time I've come across the need to remove LFS.