# How to clone git wiki page

Tags: git, github

I want to move my github wiki pages into separate repository and convert my public repository to private repository (private git repository dosen't support wiki pages).

How to clone git wiki page or how to move wiki pages between repository ?

Comment: upload into new wiki - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861701/how-to-push-wiki-to-github

Answer (score 1):

It is true that the [documentation still states](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-access-permissions-for-wikis/):

> Wikis are available in public repositories with GitHub Free, and in public and private repositories with GitHub Pro, GitHub Team, and GitHub Enterprise Cloud.

But you will find [tweets mentioning](https://twitter.com/not_xuwei_k/status/1082841505956593664):

> OK. from quickly trying out the new free GitHub account with private repos, looks like the following features are available.
>
> - GitHub Pages
> - Wiki
> - Branch protection rules

The [billing plan](https://help.github.com/articles/github-s-billing-plans/#billing-plans-for-personal-accounts) does seem to confirm though the lack of wiki for public repos: I suspect those having a wiki are students, which have access to pro feature for free.

If that is the case, I would recommend:

- [cloning your public repo wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24797660/6309)
- pushing it to a dedicate branch in your private repo.